# If $f,g : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ are continuous functions, $f(r)=g(r)$ for all $r\in \Bbb Q$, then $f=g$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

> Prove that if $f,g : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ are continuous functions and $f(r)=g(r)$ for all $r\in \Bbb Q$, then $f=g$.

Let $e\in \Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$. Let $\varepsilon>0$.

As $f,g$ are continuous, we have $\delta_1,\delta_2>0$ such that if $0<|x-e|<\delta_1$ then $|f(x)-f(e)|<\varepsilon$, idem for $g(x)$.

Then

$$|f(e)-g(e)|\leq |f(x)-f(e)|+|g(x)-g(e)|+|f(x)-g(x)|<2\varepsilon$$

Provided $|x-e|<\delta_1,\delta_2$ and $x\in \Bbb Q$.

As $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, $|f(e)-g(e)|<2\varepsilon$ implies $f(e)=g(e)$.

Is this proof alright?

Comment: It's certainly the right idea, but it needs a bit more justification, to my mind.

Comment: @CameronBuie More justification in which parts?

Comment: For a start, define what $\delta_1$, $\delta_2$, and $x$ are *before* using them. (and explain why you can choose $x$ that way.)

Comment: @ClementC. Sure, what about now?

Comment: "As the rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, we can always choose $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ in such a way" (then yes, I'd say it's fine)

Comment: Somewhere in our lives we were told "if |a| < epsilon for all epsilon > 0 then a = 0" and the very first time we heard it we all probably said "huh, what?"  Then either the teacher banged our heads into the blackboard and shouted at us, or the teacher gently explained why that had to be.  So the question is, is today the first day we heard that, and do we need to have it gently explained, or did you have a brains bashed last week and we are in the mood to bash other peoples brains?  If "|a| < epsilon => a = 0" is convincing, then the proof is good.  ... which is to say *I* think it is fine.

Comment: Also, as Clement C said, the result is true for any dense set (such as the dyadic rationals), not just the rationals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a metric space, continuity is equivalent to sequential continuity. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then there exists a sequence of rational numbers $\{r_{n}\}$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} r_{n} = x$. Then by the continuity of the difference of continuous functions, we have $0 = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(r_{n}) - g(r_{n}) = f(x) -g(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it seems correct. To simplify it, I'd recommend defining $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$. $h$ is continuous, and $0$ at all rational numbers, and if you prove that $h = 0$ (which is even simpler), this is equivalent to $f = g$.